# Why is the segmentation Fault error occuring

Tags: c, pthreads

I am getting error  **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

i have narrowed it done to these lines in function threadx

```
    while (colatz_nums[j] != 1)
         {j++;
            if ((m % 2)==0)
            { colatz_nums[j]  = m/2;}

            else
            {colatz_nums[j]  = 3 * m +1;}
        }
```

if I remove these lines I do not get the error. 
I added a test while loop and it worked 
So it must be something in these lines. 
Please point out the error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>  // pid_t
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <pthread.h>

#define N 2

void *thread (void *vargp);
void *threadx(void *vargp);

char **ptr;

int fib_nums[25] ;
int colatz_nums[25];
int last_collatz = 0;

int main()
{

    int i;
    pthread_t tid[2];
    char *msgs[N] = {
        "Hello from foo",
        "Hello from bar"
    };

    printf("Parent thread started with PID= %d and parent PID %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

    ptr = msgs;

    pthread_create(&tid[0], NULL, thread, (void *)1);
    printf(" 1st thread started with PID= %d and parent PID %d\n", getpid(), getppid());


    pthread_create(&tid[1], NULL, threadx, (void *)2 );
    printf("2nd  thread started with PID= %d and parent PID %d\n", getpid(),      getppid());

    pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);
}

void *thread(void *vargp)
{
    int myid = (int)vargp;
    static int cnt = 0;
    printf(" thread ");

    int i=cnt;
    for (;i <10 ;i=i+1)
    {
        printf("[%d]  %d\n",myid, i);
        sleep(cnt);
    }

    return NULL;
}

void *threadx(void *vargp )
{
    int myid = (int)vargp;
    static int cnt = 0;
    printf(" threadx \n" );
    int j = 0;
    int m = 8;
    colatz_nums[0] = 8;

    while (colatz_nums[j] != 1)
    {
        j++;
        if ((m % 2)==0)
        {
            colatz_nums[j]  = m/2;
        }

        else
        {
            colatz_nums[j]  = 3 * m +1;
        }
    }
    last_collatz = j;

    for (j=0; j <= last_collatz; j++)
        printf ( " j %d",colatz_nums[j]);

    printf ( "\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger? My guess is that you're going outside the array bounds.

Comment: What is the value of `j` when the segmentation fault occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never check for bound of `colatz_nums`. You are accessing it using `j` and increments it without limiting it to 24.

You first execute

`colatz_nums[0] = 8`

which sets the first value of the array to 8. Then you go to compare it with 1 which it is not and then loop until you find 1 in the array.

The problem in your loop is you start by incrementing `j` then set the value located at index `j` (which is the next value you will test against 1 in next turn of the loop) to a value that will never be 1(4 or 25 but always 4 in your example).

You will then loop forever until crash occurs(out of bound access).

Answer (score 0):

`m` is *never* changing so `colatz_nums[j]` is *continuously* being set to `4` (because `m` is eight, an even number), right up until the point where you run off the end of the array.

You can fix this by simply putting this line as the last inside that `while` loop:

```
m = colatz_nums[j];
```

or rewriting it to something like a safer variant that avoids undefined behaviour:

```
while (colatz_nums[j] != 1) {
    j++;
    if ((m % 2)==0)
        m  = m / 2;
    else
        m  = 3 * m + 1;

    if (j == sizeof(colatz_nums) / sizeof(colatz_nums[0])) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Buffer overflow\n");
        exit (1);  // or some other method of stopping
    }
    colatz_nums[j]  = m;
}
```